# How to do try catch in Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

How to do try catch in Power Automate? (something like try catch)

I have a Power Automate process (cloud, not desktop), It works well, but some times fail.

I want to get some notice when my process fail. How to  do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some recommended pattern to do `Try.. catch.. finally` from the community using `Scope` control block. [Read more](https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/office-365-en/powerautomate-en/try-catch-pattern-in-microsoft-flow/)

[image]

Comment: Could you answer this for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899370/how-to-make-the-r-n-string-work-in-teams-messages

Comment: @2015evanotes. sure let me take a look, happy to help. If this answer helped you - pls upvote/accept this answer :)

Comment: OK  :)   NO  problem.